# winsock weirdness (c++)

Tags: c++, winsock

I am trying to implement a function called "inet_pton" which will convert a string representation of an IPv4 or IPv6 (like "66.102.1.147" [google]) into binary network-byte ordered form.  Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
#if defined WIN32
int inet_pton (int af, const char *src, void *dst)

{
    const void *data;
    size_t      len;
    struct      addrinfo hints, *res;

    hints.ai_family   = af;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; 
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
    hints.ai_flags    = AI_NUMERICHOST;

    if (getaddrinfo (src, NULL, &hints, &res))
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR : inet_pton() in " << __FILE__ << " at line " << __LINE__ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "      : getaddrinfo() failed to get IP address info for \"" << src << "\"" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
...
```

So src is the incoming IP string.  However, I always get an error like

getaddrinfo() failed to get IP address info for "66.102.1.147"

Can anyone with winsock experience comment?  I also tried another method, the function

```
WSAStringToAddress ((LPTSTR)src, af, NULL, (LPSOCKADDR) &sa, &address_length)
```

But it always returns the error code WSAEINVAL, indicating an invalid IP string.  This makes no sense to me.  I'm using VS2005 as my IDE.

Comment: Which version of Windows? Vista and 2008 already have an inet_pton function.

Comment: In case someone reads this question again:
SOCK_STREAM cannot be combined with IPPROTO_UDP.
It has to be either SOCK_STREAM with IPPROTO_TCP, or SOCK_DGRAM with IPPROTO_UDP. Other combinations of those values will not work as UDP  is a datagram protocol and TCP is a stream protocol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for a start you're asking for a stream socket with UDP as a protocol and that just isn't going to happen.

Try with:

```
hints.ai_family   = af;
hints.ai_socktype = 0; 
hints.ai_protocol = 0;
hints.ai_flags    = AI_NUMERICHOST;
```

and memset it to zero first as it has extra members that you're not setting...

Also in my code I pass an empty string for the port or service when I don't have one rather than a null. The docs don't seem to specify what to do when you don't have a value; but either way an empty string works for me.

Oh, and as always in these situations, it would be useful to know what value WSAGetLastError() returns...

Comment: WSAGetLastError was returning WSAEINVAL.  Your solution worked, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

MSDN has an excellent article on using getaddrinfo:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738520(VS.85).aspx

There is even an example using AI_NUMERICHOST, which sounds like what you need. They setup their "hints" struct a bit differently than you:

```
ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
```

They don't set the other 2 properties. Maybe this will help?

Answer (score 2):

What's the value you're passing in for af? I have some code to do the same thing and the only differences between mine and yours are:

- I memset the hints structure to 0
- I always pass in `PF_UNSPEC` for ai_family
- I use `IPPROTO_TCP` rather than `IPPROTO_UDP`.

Answer (score 1):

you could also use [libcurl](http://cool.haxx.se/cvs.cgi/curl/lib/inet_pton.c?rev=1.21&content-type=text/vnd.viewcvs-markup) as a reference. reinventing the wheel isn't always necessary.